# Adding multiple conditions in SetEnvIf

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, setenv

I need to use `SetEnvIf` in my `.htaccess` file.

I also need to satisfy *multiple conditions* and then, show the required URL.

Here is my code:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Host "^" press_flag=0
SetEnvIf Request_URI '/press/$' press_flag=1
SetEnvIf Cookie 'language\_uiAAAenglishBBB' press_flag=press_flag+1
SetEnvIf press_flag 2 Request_URI='Remote_Host/eng/test.html'
```

Explanation:

1. In the first line, I am setting a variable `press_flag` to `0`.
2. Second line, I check whether the *URL* ends with this text:   `/press/`, if true, the I set the 'press_flag' to `1`.
3. Third line, I check if the cookie matches `language\_uiAAAenglishBBB` text, if true, then I increment `press_flag` value by 1.
4. Last line, I check if the `press_flag` value is 2, then I set the `HTTP_HOST` accordingly.

But, when I open `URL/press/` in browser, it is not getting redirected.

Please help to debug and fix this code.

Thanks.

Comment: Second line does not make sense, `HTTP_HOST` is the domain name, has nothing to do with the _path_ segment of the URL. And I don’t see you doing any redirecting anywhere.

Comment: @CBroe: Ok. Thanks for the correction. So, should I replace *HTTP_HOST* to *HOST*?

Comment: No, there is no environment variable called `HOST` – and if there was, HOST would still not mean “path”.

Comment: @CBroe: ok, great to know that. Can you please help me with this, so as to what changes to be made in order to achieve the target?

Comment: Should I replace HTTP_HOST with Request_URI ?

Answer (score 3):

Whilst the answer provided by @akond satisfies a solution to the problem;

I do believe this is a good example of using the `SetEnvIfExpr` Directive in response to the original OP's question of "**Adding multiple conditions in SetEnvIf**":

```
SetEnvIfExpr "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/press/$# && %{HTTP_COOKIE} == 'language\_uiAAAenglishBBB'" Request_URI='Remote_Host/eng/test.html'
```

See more details at:

- [SetEnvIfExpr Directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvifexpr)
- [Expressions in Apache HTTP Server](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/expr.html)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can redirect with `SetEnvIf`. You should use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =/press/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} \blanguage=english\b
RewriteRule .* /eng/test.html [R]
```

1. Checks if /press/ is requested
2. Checks if the cookie is set to certain value.
3. Redirection rule